# Shell script to automate SonicWall firewall SSH session not working

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, expect, heredoc

I'm trying to write a shell script (Bash) to log into a SonicWall firewall device and issue a command to perform automated backups of the devices ruleset. I prefer to do this in Bash but I will accept a python, perl, except, or applescript solution. If it cannot be done in bash please mention that.

Problems:

1.) SSH server on firewall is custom, a user name and password has to be specified after issuing a

```
$ ssh server.com
```

so no matter what username you issue e.g.

```
$ ssh admin@server.com
```

the SSH server still presents a username and password box after

2.) The SSH server is minimal and I cannot use public-keys

I tried using a here-document but it isn't working and it results in an immediate "connection closed by remote host".

The command I need to execute takes the form of this:

```
export preferences ftp "ftp.server.com" "user1" "mypassword" "output.exp"
```

Connecting gives me this:

```
$ ssh admin@server.com


Copyright (c) 2010 SonicWALL, Inc. 

User:
```

After a username is issued it brings up the password prompt:

```
User:user1
Password:
```

I tried a here-document to no avail.

```
$ ssh server <<+
user1
mypassword
export preferences ftp "ftp.server.com" "user1" "mypassword" "output.exp"
exit
+ 
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Connection to 10.1.1.1 closed by remote host.
```

I tried using echo to pipe in commands too but that doesn't work either.

Typing the commands in manually works just fine.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible with bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested, `expect` is probably what you want to use here.

Here's a short example of how to work with it from `bash` to get you started:

```
login=root
IP=127.0.01
password=helloworld
# +whatever variables you need to use

# Run the expect script from bash
expect_sh=$(expect -c "
spawn ssh $login@$IP
expect \"password:\"
send \"$password\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"cd $dest_dir\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"chmod +x $server_side_script $other_script\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"./$device_side_script\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"cat results_file\r\" 
expect \"#\"
send \"exit\r\"
")

# Output or do something with the results
echo "$expect_sh"
```

Comment: Thank you for an example that fits closely to what I need. This should be a breeze now.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the ssh session using the original `expect`, here is a nice article discussing it in detail: http://solar1.net/drupal/automating%20SSH%20with%20expect or the Python module `pexepect`: http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/346/python-how-to-access-ssh-with-pexpect/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a BASH expert but i had to do something where interactive password prompts was causing me a problem.

Basically your script needs to wait to be asked to enter login credentials, and pass them when prompted in order to login, once logged in you can issue the command.

I recommend looking at spawning "expect" sessions. Basically in your script you use expect to basically say "i expect to see password: in the response, when i do, i need to pass in the following data".

Here's the wiki page which helps explain it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

and if you google around you will find lots of help.

Comment: I figured the wait was the problem. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

that didn't work for me.

I had to pass the variables to the script at launch.

Example launch script login2.sh, with three arguments:

-bash-4.1$ ./login2.sh Jan2**** HIE_SUPER 10.244.112.182